# How to customize edit and update action in rails_admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, customization, rails-admin, controller-action

I'm using rails_admin and I think it's great. Unfortunately I can't get to override a specific action on a specific model. 
I just need to override edit and update behavior on one model. Any idea?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't right now override the standard actions - you can however create custom actions as exhibited here https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Actions

Comment: Hey, did you find any way of implementing this

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what you have tried in the past and it would be of great help if you post that but you can not try this

```
config.model 'Model' do
  edit do
    ....
  end

  update do
    ....
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, considering what you are trying to do. I believe you can achieve it using ROR callbacks too and this would be much easier.

So In your model file

```
after_update :custom_action

#define custom_action in the same model
def custom_action
  #your code goes here
end
```

You might have to check that this action is performed by the admin and that's it.

Sorry for being 4 years late. But this might help others.

Answer (score 0):

You can add additional update behavior by tapping-in to the Auditing support.

In my case, I needed to log when certain fields were changed on a particular model, along with the user that made the change.  I achieved that with:

```
RailsAdmin.config do |config|
  config.audit_with { @auditing_adapter = MyAuditor.new(self) }
end

class MyAuditor
  def update_object(object, _abstract_model, user, changes)
    if object.is_a?(SomeModel)
      changes = changes.slice(:important_field, :other_important_field)
      if changes.present?
        # ... log change ...
      end
    end
  end

  # other auditor methods (unused)
  def initialize(_controller) end
  def create_object(_object, _abstract_model, _user) end
  def delete_object(_object, _abstract_model, _user) end
  def latest() end
  def listing_for_object(*_args) end
  def listing_for_model(*_args) end
end
```